# Is the meaning of "so far" equivalent to that of "up to a certain point" in some contexts?

Tags: difference, phrase-meaning

Can "so far" and "up to a certain point" be interchangeable in certain contexts?

For example:

1. You can only go **so far**/**up to a certain point** by studying that way.
2. I couldn't get her to tell me the details. She only spoke **so far**/ **up to a certain point**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can only go so far by studying that way.

Is fine.

> I couldn't get her to tell me the details. She only spoke so far.

Is wrong.

'So far' is used like this when something is explicitly expressed as a measure of distance.  A better way to think of the phrase is:

> only go so far

"You can only go so far studying that way."

"The money only went so far, then we had to eat paper for the rest of the month."

To make your last sentence work, you can use:

> I couldn't get her to tell me the details. Our conversation only went so far.

Answer (score 1):

*so far* has an indefinite end point, while *up to a certain *point*" has a definite end point.

In example 1, it depends on the context to decide which is best.

In example 2, *details* (spoken or not) are specific items, so:

> I couldn't get her to tell me the details. She only spoke **up to a certain point**.